# Insert a line break to EndLabelString in LyX custom style

Tags: lyx, lyx-layouts

I want to create a new style of type "environment" in the LyX editor by means of writing a module, so that the user can choose and insert it from the style combobox on the toolbar.

I want to add to that style a new line with the clubs sign (♣) at the end of the style, like this:

[image: clubs sign]

I am following the manual "Customizing LYX: Features for the Advanced User" that can be found from within the help menu, and noticed the commands `EndLabelType` and `EndLabelString`, to which I passed the values

```
EndLabelType      Static
EndLabelString    "♣"
```

What is the syntax for a line break to append to "♣" so that a new line filled with ♣ would then appear in the editor?

I tried `<br/>`, `\n` and `\\` but it just outputs the strings `"<br/>"`, `\n` and `"\\"`.

Is that possible at all?

Comment: +1 Great question. I can see you put a lot of effort into trying to solve it yourself first. Specifically, I see you read the documentation and it was a good idea to try `<br/>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently possible in LyX.

Newlines are only supported in the layout tags where it is documented. For example, under "LeftDelim", the documentation specifies:

> A line break in the output can be indicated by `<br/>`

Looking at the LyX source code, the special sequence `<br/>` is indeed handled specially for only the tags that document it. For example, for LeftDelim, the following is done:

```
    case LT_LEFTDELIM:
        lex >> leftdelim_;
        leftdelim_ = support::subst(leftdelim_, from_ascii("<br/>"),
                        from_ascii("\n"));
        break;
```

Further, I'm not sure it's as simple as changing the corresponding code for EndLabelString and recompiling the source code, since I think that the code above is for adding a newline to the LaTeX output, where you want to change the LyX display.

I suggest to file an enhancement request (with component 'layout') and corresponding use case at https://www.lyx.org/trac